# Where to see what products were ordered from a quote in database when Paypal Express order not shown up in backend

Tags: magento2, paypal-express, magento2-3

A client has received a payment email from Paypal last night which was a legitimate order via his Magento 2 website with Paypal Express but the order does not appear in the backend.

Checking logs there was no response from Paypal at the point the order was being placed as it just timed out waiting for the Paypal NVP Curl connection (there have since been successful orders placed with Paypal Express on the website).

So the quote exists in the database but how do I find out what products were ordered so our client can fulfil the order? Unsure where to see this from a quote in the database...

Answer (score 0):

I found the items listed against the quote ID in the table quote_item.